# Find File By knowing the Prefix of File

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a file, to send as an attachment to a customer. The user inputs the customer name to get the e-mail address and the file number as a reference to look for the correct file in the Excel sheet. The user also inputs the file path in the Excel sheet.

The issue is that the file name is randomly generated from a different system and I could only identify the first 30 characters from the file name that contains the file number while the rest of the characters is randomly generated.

The VBA code shows "Path not found".

```
Sub SendEVAT()

Dim strLocation As String
Dim strName As String
Dim fldpath As String
Dim fldpath1 As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
Dim fsoFldr As Scripting.Folder
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim m As Long, n As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim mrow1 As Long, nrow1 As Long
Dim strbody1 As String, strbody2 As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim colm As Integer

colm = Sheets("Input").Range("N4").Value
With Worksheets("Input")
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

mrow1 = Sheets("Email Content").Cells(10, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For m = 2 To mrow1
    strbody1 = strbody1 & "<br>" & Sheets("Email Content").Cells(m, 1)
Next m

nrow1 = Sheets("Email Content").Cells(15, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For n = 2 To nrow1
   strbody2 = strbody2 & "<br>" & Sheets("Email Content").Cells(n, 2)
Next n

For i = 1 To lastrow - 1

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fldpath = Sheets("Input").Range("N2") & "\" & Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 6).Value & "*"
    Set fsoFldr = fso.getfolder(fldpath)

    If Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1 - 1, 2) Then

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Set rng = Sheets("Input").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, colm))

    For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile) = "pdf" Then
        fldpath1 = fsoFile.Path
        End If
    Next fsoFile

    If Len(fldpath1) = 0 And Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1 + 1, 2) Then

            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = "File Not Found"
            With OutMail

            .Display

            End With

    ElseIf Len(Dir(fldpath1)) = 0 And Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1 + 1, 2) Then

            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = "File Not Found"

    Else

    Set rng = Union(rng, Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, colm)))

            With OutMail
                .To = Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 9).Value
                .Subject = Sheets("Input").Range("N3").Value & " " & Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
                .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:13'>" & strbody1 & "<p>" & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & "<p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:13'>" & strbody2 & "<p>"

                strLocation = fldpath1
                .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
                If Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 2, 2) Then
                    If Sheets("Input").Range("N1").Value = "Send" Then
                    .Send
                    Else
                    .Display
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = "Sent"
            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = Date
            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = "E-mail"

    End If

    ElseIf Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1 - 1, 2) Then

    For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile) = "pdf" Then
        fldpath1 = fsoFile.Path
        End If
    Next fsoFile

    If Len(fldpath1) = 0 And Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1 + 1, 2) Then

            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = "File Not Found"

            With OutMail

            .Display

            End With

    ElseIf Len(Dir(fldpath1)) = 0 And Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1 + 1, 2) Then

            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = "File Not Found"

    Else

    Set rng = Union(rng, Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, colm)))

            With OutMail
                .To = Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 9).Value
                .Subject = Sheets("Input").Range("N3").Value & " " & Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
                .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:13'>" & strbody1 & "<p>" & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & "<p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:13'>" & strbody2 & "<p>"
                strLocation = fldpath1
                .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
                If Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 2, 2) Then
                    If Sheets("Input").Range("N1").Value = "Send" Then
                    .Send
                    Else
                    .Display
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = "Sent"
            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = Date
            Sheets("Input").Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = "E-mail"

    End If

    End If

Next i

On Error GoTo 0

'enter code here'End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Below is the display of the Excel sheet that will be used by the user

[Excel Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtIPf.png)

How do I search for the file knowing only the first 30 characters of the file name?

Comment: Use `DIR` with wildcards "what you know*"` or  `left(filename,30)="what you know" and filename like "what you know*"` for safety i'd loop the folder and if there are more than 1 found, alert the user, if you know 100% there can only be one, then do this, without checking for multiple files.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav hi, yes I think I can use the DIR function. Thank you for your suggestion